# Entropy of $Y=bX$

Tags: entropy

If I have two random variables $Y$ and $U$ related as $Y=bU$, where $b>0$ is a constant and knowing that

$\text{H}(x)$ represents the shannon entropy, such that:
$$
 \text{H}(x)=−\int \text{p}(x) \ \text{log}_2(\text{p}(x)) \ dx
$$

Then, what is the entropy of $\text{H}(Y)$ in terms of $U$? Can I expand $H(Y)$ in somehow approximately to this form: $\text{H}(U) - log_2(b)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the density $p_Y$ of $Y$ is related to that of $U$ by 
$p_Y(y) = p_U(y/b)/b$.  Then
$$\eqalign{H(Y) &= - \int_\mathbb R p_Y(y)\; \log_2(p_Y(y))\; dy \cr
&=- \dfrac{1}{b} \int_\mathbb R p_U(y/b)\; (\log_2(p_U(y/b)) - \log_2(b))\; dy\cr
&= - \int_\mathbb R p_U(u)\; (\log_2(p_U(u)) - \log_2(b))\; du\cr 
&= H(U) + \log_2(b)}$$