# Justification of $h(aX) = h(X) + \log|a|$ (Differential entropy under scaling)

Tags: entropy, differential

Being $h$ the differential entropy, defined by $h(X) = - \int f(x) \log(f(x)) dx$, where $X$ is a random variable.

I know there's a property of $h$ that states that: $h(Y) = h(X) + \log|a|$, being $Y=aX$, where $a \ne 0$ is a deterministic constant and $X$ is a random variable.

I was wondering which is the justification of this for the case of:

$Y=aX$, and the PDF of Y $f(y)=(1/a) \cdot f(x/a)$.

Comment: If yes, do you know the PDF of $a X$, when the PDF of $X$ is $a$?

Comment: http://reeves.ee.duke.edu/information_theory/lecture7-Differential_Entropy.pdf page 5

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1160561/entropy-of-y-bx?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

As you mention, if $X$ has the pdf $f(x)$, $Y$ has the pdf $a^{-1} f(a^{-1}x)$.
This can be seen by taking the derivative of the cdf $F_Y(y) = P(Y \le y) = P(X \le a^{-1} y)$, as $\frac{d}{d y} F_X(a^{-1} y) = a^{-1} F'_X(a^{-1} y)$ holds by the chain rule.

Therefore for $a > 0$,
\begin{align}
h(Y)
& = -\int a^{-1} f(a^{-1}x) \log\big(a^{-1} f(a^{-1}x)\big) dx \\
& = -\int a^{-1} f(a^{-1}x) \log\big(f(a^{-1}x)\big) dx - \int a^{-1} f(a^{-1}x) \log(a^{-1}) dx \tag{1}\\
& = -\int f(x) \log(f(x)) dx + \log(a) \cdot \int a^{-1} f(a^{-1}x) dx \tag{2} \\
& = -\int f(x) \log(f(x)) dx + \log(a)
= h(X) + \log|a| \tag{3}
\end{align}
holds.

We use the following three facts:

1. $\log(a b) = \log(a) + \log(b)$ and $\log(a^{-1}) = - \log(a)$ for $a,b > 0$.
2. $\int g(a^{-1} x) dx = a \int g(x) dx$.
3. $\int f(x) dx = 1$, when $f$ is a pdf.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. But why are we taking the value of a >0 and why do you have log of absolute value there?

Comment: @SAT I just did the proof for $a > 0$ because it works analogously when $a < 0$. Furthermore, if $a > 0$, $a = | a |$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you elaborate on why we are using the absolute value in case of positive a?

Comment: @SAT It is not necessary, but I wanted it to look exactly like the identity in question.

Comment: But if we merge two cases into one having 1/|a|, can we still do the change of variable in the integral?

Comment: I have created one question, I would be very grateful if you could have a look, since I feel stuck by the usage of absolute value. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3941181/how-to-approach-change-of-variable-in-integral-in-hax-hx-loga-scal